# Function template substitution bug in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013

Let there be a class `TArray` which has operator[]. The return type of `Tarray[index]` is known, let's call it `TResult`, but the type of `index` itself, `TIndex`, I want to figure out. To this end I've defined the 
following template.

```
template<class TArray, class TResult>
struct ArrayIndexType
{
    template<class TIndex>
    using OperatorFunc = TResult(TArray::*)(TIndex);

    template<class TIndex> 
    static TIndex test(OperatorFunc<TIndex>);

    using type = decltype(test(&TArray::operator[]));
};
```

and it actually works for std::vector:

```
cout << typeid(ArrayIndexType<vector<double>, /*TResult=*/double&>::type).name();
// output:    unsigned int.
```

but when I do the same for simplest inheritance:

```
class DoubleVec: public vector<double>
{};
cout << typeid(ArrayIndexType<DoubleVec, /*TResult=*/double&>::type).name();
```

I get compilation error C2664: 'TIndex ArrayIndexType::test(TResult (__thiscall DoubleVec::* )(TIndex))' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'overloaded-function' to 'double &(__thiscall DoubleVec::* )(unsigned int)'

which basically means that compiler cannot choose between 2 overloads for operator[] defined in vector: `double& vector::operator[](size_t)`, and `const double& vector::operator[](size_t)`.
Is this a bug in MSVS 2013 or am I doing something wrong?

Maybe there is better way to achieve the goal, i.e. to obtain the type of argument of operator[]?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug. The type of `&DoubleVec::operator[]` is still "pointer to member function of `std::vector<double>`", and the compiler can't deduce a "pointer to member function of `DoubleVec`" from it.

This is all pretty much pointless anyway for standard containers:

```
template<class T>
using ArrayIndexType = typename T::size_type;
```

Alternatively, template `OperatorFunc` on the class type as well:

```
template<class TArray, class TResult>
struct ArrayIndexType
{
    template<class T, class TIndex>
    using OperatorFunc = TResult(T::*)(TIndex);

    template<class T, class TIndex> 
    static TIndex test(OperatorFunc<T, TIndex>);

    using type = decltype(test(&TArray::operator[]));
};
```

Comment: Brilliant! Your second proposal is working and is really what I need, because this macro is going to be used not only for std::vector, really.